# How to solve this differential equation: $\frac{du}{dt}=1+u+t+tu$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this differential equation: $\frac{du}{dt}=1+u+t+tu$ ?
It would be easy, if it is a separable differential equation, but it's not. I don't know how to manipulate the variables so that I can solve it. Could you help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is separable, $\frac{du}{dt}=(1+t)(1+u)$.

Comment: If I have a non-separable differential equation, is there any general solution for it?

Comment: There is no universal method.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{du}{dt} = (t+1)(u+1) \to \dfrac{du}{u+1} = (t+1)dt$

Comment: Calculation problem